# Making large text box for ajax search

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I am making an AJAX application where the user can input the name of a movie and the results from the database will be loaded through jquery from a PHP API, However I am unsure how to implement a text box that will:

(a) Be the focus of attention on the page (i.e. quite large with a glow around it)

(b) automatically execute a function that uses jquery to make an ajax request on every time a letter is entered (kind of like google instant)

Any suggestions would be very greatly appreciated,
thanks, RayQuang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using jQuery use the .keyup function and then put your code that gets something from your php script inside that function or do what I do and have your getting done by another function and call that from inside the .keyup function like this:

```
 function getData(){
            data=$('#textareaid').val();
            $.post('http://example.come/ajaxcontroller.php', {data: data},
            function(data) {// Proccess returned ajax here, you could also use one of the ajax functions instead of .post});
          }

$(document).ready(function() {              
$('#textareaid').keyup(function(e) { getData();}
}
```

As for the glow, either use css to make a larger 3d border around your textarea (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp) or wrap it in a div and make a background that accomplishes the specific effect your looking for.

Answer (score 1):

a) For the glow, will an outline or a border do?

b) Use an `<textarea>` tag and trap its `onchange` event to send the AJAX request each time. You can make the textarea as large as you want by defining `rows` and `cols`